# How to open multiple Kindle books at the same time?

Tags: macos, kindle

How can I open several instances of the kindle reader at the same time, so that I can have a different book open in each one?

I found this:

[Multiple Kindle Windows on PC, Mac](http://www.amazon.com/forum/kindle?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=Fx1D7SY3BVSESG&cdThread=Tx3F7B4V6Y5QGMT)

Which suggests using multiple cloud readers, but I want to use the desktop version.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this specifically with Kindle, but it works for most apps that don't normally open a second instance...

In Terminal
`open -n`
(note the space after -n) 
then drop the Kindle app onto the Terminal window to auto-fill the path to it & hit  <kbd>Return⏎</kbd>

back in Terminal,  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>↑</kbd>  then  <kbd>Return⏎</kbd>  will repeat that command & should open a second instance.

Comment: the kindle app starts but then it closes, it seems to detect that there is another instance running and then decides to close down to make sure that only one instance is running